# Subset of military time in R

Tags: r, csv, time, subset

I have a .csv file in R that I want to take a subset of using time.

The data look something like this:[image: csv data in R]

You can recreate a sample of the data using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

tibble(
  trap = "LS_trap_29u",
  serial_no = "D900000039601641",
  canopy_understory = "u",
  time = str_pad(round(runif(28, min = 0, max = 2300),-2), 4, pad = "0"),
  temp = round(runif(28, min = 20, max = 30), 2),
  humidity = NA
)
```

I want to pick out certain parts of the data based on time to use for later statistics. I want to select all the data that takes place between 000 and 0100 for instance I do this: `mid_temp <- subset(my_file,time>0&time<100)`

Doing this gets me a subset of the original, but its a subset containing lots of different times. I get the same result from other subset commands such as:

`mid_temp <- subset(my_file,time>0&time<1)`

When I do `data.class(my_file$time)` it returns "character"

How can I create appropriate subsets from my data based on time?

Comment: Perhaps you need `my_file$time <- as.numeric(my_file$time)` (may use `as.integer` if you are certain of its integrality). I'm guessing your `$date` field is also `character`, not `Date` or `POSIXct`.

Comment: Your first `subset` code would work if you used `as.numeric(time)` rather than `time`.

Comment: @r2evans Your solution worked. Post it as a response so I can accept it.

Comment: I would like to know how to convert my Date column as well, but that's a different question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment (@Erin too), the problem is that you are attempting `character`-comparison. Converting to `numeric` (or `integer` if you are confident of integrality) will help:

```
 my_file$time <- as.numeric(my_file$time)
```

or do it during the test if you want/need to keep the column `character`:

```
subset(my_file, as.numeric(time) > 0 & as.numeric(time) < 100)
```

though this has the overhead of converting twice; better to convert once and re-use.